# Image tiles for building moon map using leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I was trying to find a set of images (png) tiles for different zoom levels, for building a TileLayer of a map of moon surface.

If anyone has worked on building a moon map, and drawing crater's coordinates on the moon map. Please help me find moon surface map tiles.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use WMS services from NASA/USGS, i.e. from https://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/ogc/Examples.htm. Before using WMS in Leaflet, do read the [Leaflet WMS/TMS tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html).

With a couple of `getCapabilities` queries and reading that tutorial, making a moon map becomes quite simple:

```
var map = L.map('leaflet', {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 0
});

var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://www.mapaplanet.org/explorer-bin/imageMaker.cgi?map=Moon', {
    layers: 'lunar_lidar',
    attribution: '<a href="http://www.usgs.gov/">United States Geological Survey</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

See that [example live in a plunker over here](https://plnkr.co/edit/quOTuKhLHBBsufEAIh3u?p=preview).

[image: Leaflet moon map]

---

The mosaic layer used above is a LIDAR elevation profile with hipsometric tint and hillshading. Be aware that there might or might not be true-color mosaics, other elevation mosaics, and lots of remote sensing data mosaics. Be aware that there are more space/geo organizations than NASA/USGS that might offer similar services.

Be aware that the map projections available through WMS might not be what you expect. Be aware of the usage conditions of those WMS services. And read the Leaflet WMS tutorial.